# Reading & cbinding varying number of files

Tags: r, loops

I have to write an R script where I want to load different numbers of files at different times. The files are loaded into data frames and certain columns of the data frames are extracted. The columns are then merged with the `cbind` function. My problem is that I do not know how I can adapt to varying numbers of files that are loaded from time to time, because there may be 3 vectors for `cbind` at one time or 5 vectors at another time. So how can I give `cbind` a number of vectors so that it doesn't output errors when it doesn't get all vectors? This happens when I give it a fixed number.

```
raw1 <- read.table()
raw2 <- read.table()
vec1 <- raw1[,2]
vec2 <- raw2[,2]
cbind(vec1,vec2,vec3)
```

I know I'd better write sth interactive such as a `tcltk` dialog and the some kind of loop. Maybe you could provide me with some kind of an idea of how an effective loop could be structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the data frames in a list and then cbind them using do.call(). This is a good way to cbind lists of arbitrary length.

```
datalist <- lapply(filenames, function(i) read.table(i)[, 2])
# ... where filenames are the names of the files you want to read, and 
# passing any additional parameters to read.table that are needed 
# Then cbind all the entries of datalist 
do.call(cbind, datalist)
```

Comment: Thanks, I read sth similar before but did not understand it. I do not understand an error message, though :
     Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
    line 2 did not have xx elements

Comment: Hmm this sounds like there is a formatting issue in one of your files.. Maybe you should figure out which one it is (eg by printing i inside function(i), so when it crashes you know which one it's trying to read) and then inspect the second line of that file

Comment: After inserting the argument fill=TRUE in read.table it worked.